# Python Flask extracting results from endpoint

Tags: python, flask

In the Flask script below, I want to use the results of the endpoint '`/three`' in my endpoint '`/five`'.

The endpoint for '`/three`' works fine, however when I try the endpoint '`/five`', I get the error: `TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable`.

How do I correctly use the output of '/three' to compute '/five'?

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/three')
def three():
    return {'message':3}

@app.route('/five')
def five():
    old_message =   redirect(url_for('three'))['message'] # expect to return 3
    new_message = {'message':old_message + 2 } # 3+2 = 5

    return new_message # expecting {'message':5}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Comment: redirect return a url

Comment: thanks @DeanVanGreunen, is there a way I can get the dict/json of the output of the endpoint /three ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to trigger the `three` method via http request, you could use `requests` package, then JSON-parse it, manipulate and return to the client:

```
from flask import jsonify
import requests
import json
...
...
...
@app.route('/three')
def three():
    return {'message':3}

@app.route('/five')
def five():
    http_req = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/three')
    my_three_json = json.loads(http_req.text)
    my_three_json["message"] += 2
    return jsonify(my_three_json)
```